# How to consider a long "integer" as a string in SQL query when useing R to connect HANA?

Tags: sql, r, type-conversion, hana, rodbc

I am using R package RODBC to connect HANA. One of the columns is like a long integer, but actually used as a string such as 2772161413309, 4239530000000239. SQL takes such data as integers. In R, these numbers are shown in scientific notation like 2.77136e+12. my code that pick up some values from this column is:

```
> a <- sqlQuery(ch,paste(' SELECT "_tmSum"."/BIC/ZTMCARDNO"
                           FROM "SAPB1P"."/BIC/AZ_RT_A212" "_tmSum"
                           WHERE "_tmSum"."/BIC/ZTMCARDNO">0 AND "_tmSum"."CALDAY" BETWEEN',StartDate,'AND',EndDate,'  '))
```

I have the following error information:

```
[1] "S1000 339 [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB DLL][HDBODBC] General error;339 invalid number:  [6930] exception 6930:\nims_search_api/Search/PartSearchImpl.cpp:427\nattribute value is not a number\n"                                                                                                               
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect ' SELECT                        \"_tmSum\".\"/BIC/ZTMCARDNO\"\n                       FROM \"SAPB1P\".\"/BIC/AZ_RT_A212\" \"_tmSum\"\n
```

Here, "_tmSum"."/BIC/ZTMCARDNO" is the comlumn including long integers. I want to consider it to be string and pick up some values that is not 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the problem here is *not* with the way `R` and `SAP HANA` handle floats.
In both systems 2.77136e+12 is recognised correctly:

R:

```
> x <- 2.77136e+12
> x
[1] 2.77136e+12
> typeof(x)
[1] "double"
```

HANA:

```
select to_double('2.77136e+12') from dummy;

> 2771360000000
```

The error you receive, however, seems to come from the data processing within the `"SAPB1P"."/BIC/AZ_RT_A212"` view.

Could it be that in it some data type conversion is performed? Based on the name it looks like a BW table - often the BW data types are mapped to character type SQL data types. So, it might be worthwhile checking what data types are used in the model.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a misunderstanding about SQL. When the integer is really long, like 13 or more digits. SQL will consider it as a string. Those integers shows in R in scientific notation way because R considers them as integers. So, in SQL query, just using character related methods to deal with them is OK.